# Декодирование аудиофайла в сырые данные (decode, resampling, encode) используя FFmpeg API

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decode

Моя задача, открыть существующий аудиофайл с расширением **`mka`** ([Matroska](https://www.matroska.org/index.html) контейнер) и извлечь аудиоданные. Аудиоданные могут быть различного типа - `PCM_ALAW`, `PCM_MULAW`, `S16LE`, `S16BE`, `GSM`, `OPUS` и так далее. Также должна быть реализована логика преобразования аудиоформата из одного в другой (например, из `PCM_ALAW` в `PCM_MULAW`). Главная проблема, которую не могу решить, это так называемый `RESAMPLING`. Но чтобы найти решение этой проблемы, я постараюсь подробно описать логику самого проекта.

Одной из важнейших реализаций декодера является преобразование извлеченных данных из одного формата в другой. Для этого, нам нужно пройти несколько шагов:

1. Открытие входящего стрима

```cpp
bool AudioDecoder::openInputStream(void)
{
    qint32 errorCode = -1;
    if (p_frmCtx == nullptr) {
        // Open the input file to read from it
        if ((errorCode = avformat_open_input(&p_frmCtx,
                 m_settings.inputFile().toStdString().c_str(), nullptr, nullptr)) < 0) {
            p_frmCtx = nullptr;
            qDebug() << QString("Could not open input file: %1 (error: %2)").arg(
                            m_settings.inputFile()).arg(getMessageByErrorCode(errorCode));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

2. Поиск индекса аудиопотока и определения аудиокодека

```cpp
bool AudioDecoder::findInputStream(void)
{
    qint32 errorCode = -1;
    if (p_frmCtx != nullptr) {
        // Get information on the input file
        if ((errorCode = avformat_find_stream_info(p_frmCtx, nullptr)) < 0) {
            avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
            qDebug() << QString("Could not open find stream info (error: %1)").arg(getMessageByErrorCode(errorCode));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

3. Проверка всех потоков на наличие содержимого аудиопотока

```cpp
bool AudioDecoder::checkInputStream(void)
{
    if (p_frmCtx != nullptr) {
        m_streamIndex = -1;
        if (p_frmCtx->nb_streams != 1) {
            for (quint32 i = 0; i < p_frmCtx->nb_streams; ++i) {
                if (p_frmCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                    m_streamIndex = i;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (p_frmCtx->streams[0]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            m_streamIndex = 0;
            return true;
        }
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
    }
    return false;
}
```

4. Поиск подходящего кодека для декодирования потока

```cpp
bool AudioDecoder::openDecoderForInputStream(void)
{
    // Find a decoder for the audio stream
    AVCodec* inputCodec = nullptr;
    if (!(inputCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(
              (p_frmCtx)->streams[m_streamIndex]->codecpar->codec_id))) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        return false;
    }
    // Allocate a new decoding context.
    p_iCdcCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(inputCodec);
    if (!p_iCdcCtx) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        return false;
    }
    // Initialize the stream parameters with demuxer information.
    qint32 error = -1;
    if ((error = avcodec_parameters_to_context(p_iCdcCtx,
             (p_frmCtx)->streams[m_streamIndex]->codecpar)) < 0) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        avcodec_free_context(&p_iCdcCtx);
        return false;
    }
    // Open the decoder for the audio stream to use it later
    if ((error = avcodec_open2(p_iCdcCtx, inputCodec, nullptr)) < 0) {
        avcodec_free_context(&p_iCdcCtx);
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        return false;
    }
    av_dump_format(p_frmCtx, 0, m_settings.inputFile().toStdString().c_str(), 0);
    return true;
}
```

5. Установка желаемого кодека для кодирования декодированных данных

```cpp
bool AudioDecoder::openEncoderForOutputStream(void)
{
    AVCodec* audio_avc = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(
                m_settings.audioCodec().toStdString().c_str());
    if (!audio_avc) {
        return false;
    }
    p_oCdcCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(audio_avc);
    if (!p_oCdcCtx) {
        return false;
    }
    
    p_oCdcCtx->channels              = m_settings.channelCount();
    p_oCdcCtx->channel_layout        = av_get_default_channel_layout(m_settings.channelCount());
    p_oCdcCtx->sample_rate           = m_settings.sampleRate();
    p_oCdcCtx->sample_fmt            = audio_avc->sample_fmts[0];
    p_oCdcCtx->bit_rate              = m_settings.constBitRate();
    p_oCdcCtx->time_base.num         = 1;
    p_oCdcCtx->time_base.num         = static_cast<int>(m_settings.sampleRate());
    p_oCdcCtx->strict_std_compliance = FF_COMPLIANCE_EXPERIMENTAL;
    if (avcodec_open2(p_oCdcCtx, audio_avc, nullptr) < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

6. Извлечение всех аудиоданных, декодирование, кодирование, сохранение в буфер

```cpp
QByteArray AudioDecoder::getAllData(void)
{
    QByteArray arr;
    p_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!p_frame) {
        return arr;
    }
    AVPacket p_packet;
    av_init_packet(&p_packet);
    int err = 0;

    while ((err = av_read_frame(p_frmCtx, &p_packet)) != AVERROR_EOF) {
        if (err != 0) {
            break;
        }

        // Does the packet belong to the correct stream ?
        if (p_packet.stream_index != m_streamIndex) {
            // Free the buffers used by the frame and reset all fields.
            av_packet_unref(&p_packet);
            continue;
        }

        int response = avcodec_send_packet(p_iCdcCtx, &p_packet);
        if (response < 0) {
            return arr;
        }

        while (response >= 0) {
            response = avcodec_receive_frame(p_iCdcCtx, p_frame);
            if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
                break;
            }
            else if (response < 0) {
                return arr;
            }
            else {

                AVPacket* output_packet = av_packet_alloc();
                if (!output_packet) {
                    return arr;
                }

                int response = avcodec_send_frame(p_oCdcCtx, p_frame);
                while (response >= 0) {
                    response = avcodec_receive_packet(p_oCdcCtx, output_packet);
                    if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (response < 0) {
                        return arr;
                    }
                    else {

                        av_packet_rescale_ts(output_packet, p_oCdcCtx->time_base, p_iCdcCtx->time_base);
                        output_packet->stream_index = m_streamIndex;
                        // Save decoded - encoded audio data
                        for (int i = 0; i < output_packet->size; ++i) {
                            arr.push_back(output_packet->data[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                av_packet_unref(output_packet);
                av_packet_free(&output_packet);
                av_frame_unref(p_frame);
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(&p_packet);
    }
    av_packet_unref(&p_packet);
    av_frame_free(&p_frame);
    return arr;
}
```

Это и есть основные функции для извлечения аудиоданных, декодирования и кодирования в нужный нам формат.

Как было сказано ранее, моя проблема заключается в том, что я не могу правильно реализовать процесс преобразования частоты дискретизации, изменения количества каналов и формата аудиосэмплов (**Resampling**) перед кодированием данных и сохранением их в буфер. Я попробывал логику из [данного](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/resampling_audio_8c-example.html) примера, но я столкнулся с проблемой.

При тестировании, в качестве входящего файла я использовал аудиофайл со звуком `stereo` (2 канала). При выходе, я ему задал `mono` звучание (1 канал). Но аудиофайл стал воспроизводиться с большими помехами. Также, я не смог реализовать изменение частоты дискретизации. Как мне это реализовать ?

Знаю лишь одно, что использовать `Resampling` нужно перед кодированием в другой формат (`encoder`). Думаю, что [этот](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcode_aac_8c-example.html) пример имеет нужный функционал, для того, чтобы реализовать `Resampling`.

Прилагаю полный код проекта:

*PS Игнорируется класс `AudioDecoderSettings`, так как это простой класс настройки декодера.*

Также, стоит знать, что это всего лишь тестовая версия, и скорее всего (**наверняка**) есть утечки памяти и другие проблемы.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AudioDecoderSettings settings;
    // Входной файл
    settings.setInputFile("/home/test/ulaw-8000-64kbs-ch2.mka"); 
    // На выходе, я хочу получить такую дискретизацию
    settings.setSampleRate(8000);
    // На выходе, я хочу получить такое количество каналов
    settings.setChannelCount(1); 
    // На выходе, я хочу получить такой формат аудио
    settings.setAudioCodec("pcm_alaw"); 
    // На выходе, я хочу получить такой битрейт
    settings.setConstBitRate(64000); 

    AudioDecoder decoder(settings);

    // Инициализирую все зависимости библиотеки и
    // открывю входящий файл для извлечения аудиоданных.
    if (!decoder.init()) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Файл, в котором будут сохранены извлеченные аудиоданные.
    QFile file("/home/test/pcm_alaw.bin");
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    auto res = decoder.getAllData();
    file.write(res.data(), res.size());
    file.close();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**audiodecoder.h**

```cpp
class AudioDecoder {
public:
    AudioDecoder(const AudioDecoderSettings& settings);
    AudioDecoder& operator=(const AudioDecoder& other) = delete;
    AudioDecoder& operator=(AudioDecoder&& other) = delete;
    AudioDecoder(const AudioDecoder& other) = delete;
    AudioDecoder(AudioDecoder&& other) = delete;
    ~AudioDecoder(void);

    bool init(void);
    QByteArray getAllData(void);
    bool term(void);

protected:
    QString getMessageByErrorCode(const qint32& code);
    bool openInputStream(void);
    bool checkInputStream(void);
    bool findInputStream(void);
    bool initResampler(void);
    bool openDecoderForInputStream(void);
    bool openEncoderForOutputStream(void);

protected:
    int m_streamIndex{ 0 };
    bool m_initialized{ false };
    AVFrame* p_frame = nullptr;
    AVFormatContext* p_frmCtx = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* p_iCdcCtx = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* p_oCdcCtx = nullptr;
    AudioDecoderSettings m_settings;
    struct SwrContext* swr_ctx;
};
```

**aduiodecoder.cpp**

```cpp
void printStreamInformation(const AVCodecContext* codecCtx, int audioStreamIndex)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Codec: %s\n", codecCtx->codec->long_name);
    if (codecCtx->codec->sample_fmts != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Supported sample formats: ");
        for (int i = 0; codecCtx->codec->sample_fmts[i] != -1; ++i) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", av_get_sample_fmt_name(codecCtx->codec->sample_fmts[i]));
            if (codecCtx->codec->sample_fmts[i + 1] != -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, ", ");
            }
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "---------\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Stream:        %7d\n", audioStreamIndex);
    fprintf(stderr, "Sample Format: %7s\n", av_get_sample_fmt_name(codecCtx->sample_fmt));
    fprintf(stderr, "Sample Rate:   %7d\n", codecCtx->sample_rate);
    fprintf(stderr, "Sample Size:   %7d\n", av_get_bytes_per_sample(codecCtx->sample_fmt));
    fprintf(stderr, "Channels:      %7d\n", codecCtx->channels);
    fprintf(stderr, "Planar:        %7d\n", av_sample_fmt_is_planar(codecCtx->sample_fmt));
}

bool AudioDecoder::openInputStream(void)
{
    qint32 errorCode = -1;
    if (p_frmCtx == nullptr) {
        // Open the input file to read from it
        if ((errorCode = avformat_open_input(&p_frmCtx,
                 m_settings.inputFile().toStdString().c_str(), nullptr, nullptr)) < 0) {
            p_frmCtx = nullptr;
            qDebug() << QString("Could not open input file: %1 (error: %2)").arg(
                            m_settings.inputFile()).arg(getMessageByErrorCode(errorCode));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool AudioDecoder::findInputStream(void)
{
    qint32 errorCode = -1;
    if (p_frmCtx != nullptr) {
        // Get information on the input file
        if ((errorCode = avformat_find_stream_info(p_frmCtx, nullptr)) < 0) {
            avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
            qDebug() << QString("Could not open find stream info (error: %1)").arg(getMessageByErrorCode(errorCode));
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool AudioDecoder::checkInputStream(void)
{
    if (p_frmCtx != nullptr) {
        m_streamIndex = -1;
        if (p_frmCtx->nb_streams != 1) {
            for (quint32 i = 0; i < p_frmCtx->nb_streams; ++i) {
                if (p_frmCtx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                    m_streamIndex = i;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (p_frmCtx->streams[0]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            m_streamIndex = 0;
            return true;
        }
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
    }
    return false;
}

bool AudioDecoder::openDecoderForInputStream(void)
{
    // Find a decoder for the audio stream
    AVCodec* inputCodec = nullptr;
    if (!(inputCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(
              (p_frmCtx)->streams[m_streamIndex]->codecpar->codec_id))) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        return false;
    }
    // Allocate a new decoding context.
    p_iCdcCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(inputCodec);
    if (!p_iCdcCtx) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        return false;
    }
    // Initialize the stream parameters with demuxer information.
    qint32 error = -1;
    if ((error = avcodec_parameters_to_context(p_iCdcCtx,
             (p_frmCtx)->streams[m_streamIndex]->codecpar)) < 0) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        avcodec_free_context(&p_iCdcCtx);
        return false;
    }
    // Open the decoder for the audio stream to use it later
    if ((error = avcodec_open2(p_iCdcCtx, inputCodec, nullptr)) < 0) {
        avcodec_free_context(&p_iCdcCtx);
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
        return false;
    }
    av_dump_format(p_frmCtx, 0, m_settings.inputFile().toStdString().c_str(), 0);
    return true;
}

bool AudioDecoder::init(void)
{
    if (m_initialized) {
        qDebug() << "The decoder is already initialized";
        return true;
    }
    if (!openInputStream()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!findInputStream()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!checkInputStream()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!openDecoderForInputStream()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!openEncoderForOutputStream()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!initResampler()) {
        return false;
    }

    printStreamInformation(p_iCdcCtx, m_streamIndex);

    return m_initialized = true;
}

QString AudioDecoder::getMessageByErrorCode(const qint32& code)
{
    if (code < 0) {
        char errorBuffer[255]{ '0' };
        av_strerror(code, errorBuffer, sizeof(errorBuffer));
        return QString(errorBuffer);
    }
    return QString();
}

AudioDecoder::AudioDecoder(const AudioDecoderSettings& settings)
    : m_streamIndex(0)
    , m_initialized(false)
    , p_frame(nullptr)
    , p_frmCtx(nullptr)
    , p_iCdcCtx(nullptr)
    , p_oCdcCtx(nullptr)
    , m_settings(settings)
{
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
}

AudioDecoder::~AudioDecoder(void)
{
    term();
}

bool AudioDecoder::term(void)
{
    if (!m_initialized) {
        return false;
    }
    if (swr_ctx) {
        swr_free(&swr_ctx);
    }
    if (p_iCdcCtx != nullptr) {
        avcodec_free_context(&p_iCdcCtx);
    }
    if (p_oCdcCtx != nullptr) {
        avcodec_free_context(&p_oCdcCtx);
    }
    if (p_frmCtx != nullptr) {
        avformat_close_input(&p_frmCtx);
    }
    m_initialized = false;
    return true;
}

bool AudioDecoder::openEncoderForOutputStream(void)
{
    AVCodec* audio_avc = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(
                m_settings.audioCodec().toStdString().c_str());
    if (!audio_avc) {
        return false;
    }
    p_oCdcCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(audio_avc);
    if (!p_oCdcCtx) {
        return false;
    }

    p_oCdcCtx->channels              = m_settings.channelCount();
    p_oCdcCtx->channel_layout        = av_get_default_channel_layout(m_settings.channelCount());
    p_oCdcCtx->sample_rate           = m_settings.sampleRate();
    p_oCdcCtx->sample_fmt            = audio_avc->sample_fmts[0];
    p_oCdcCtx->bit_rate              = m_settings.constBitRate();
    p_oCdcCtx->time_base.num         = 1;
    p_oCdcCtx->time_base.num         = static_cast<int>(m_settings.sampleRate());
    p_oCdcCtx->strict_std_compliance = FF_COMPLIANCE_EXPERIMENTAL;
    if (avcodec_open2(p_oCdcCtx, audio_avc, nullptr) < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

QByteArray AudioDecoder::getAllData(void)
{
    QByteArray arr;
    p_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!p_frame) {
        return arr;
    }
    AVPacket p_packet;
    av_init_packet(&p_packet);
    int err = 0;

    while ((err = av_read_frame(p_frmCtx, &p_packet)) != AVERROR_EOF) {
        if (err != 0) {
            break;
        }

        // Does the packet belong to the correct stream ?
        if (p_packet.stream_index != m_streamIndex) {
            // Free the buffers used by the frame and reset all fields.
            av_packet_unref(&p_packet);
            continue;
        }

        int response = avcodec_send_packet(p_iCdcCtx, &p_packet);
        if (response < 0) {
            return arr;
        }

        while (response >= 0) {
            response = avcodec_receive_frame(p_iCdcCtx, p_frame);
            if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
                break;
            }
            else if (response < 0) {
                return arr;
            }
            else {

                AVPacket* output_packet = av_packet_alloc();
                if (!output_packet) {
                    return arr;
                }

                int response = avcodec_send_frame(p_oCdcCtx, p_frame);
                while (response >= 0) {
                    response = avcodec_receive_packet(p_oCdcCtx, output_packet);
                    if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (response < 0) {
                        return arr;
                    }
                    else {

                        av_packet_rescale_ts(output_packet, p_oCdcCtx->time_base, p_iCdcCtx->time_base);
                        output_packet->stream_index = m_streamIndex;
                        // Save decoded - encoded audio data
                        for (int i = 0; i < output_packet->size; ++i) {
                            arr.push_back(output_packet->data[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                av_packet_unref(output_packet);
                av_packet_free(&output_packet);
                av_frame_unref(p_frame);
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(&p_packet);
    }
    av_packet_unref(&p_packet);
    av_frame_free(&p_frame);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: что ты имеешь в виду под «сырыми данными», которые хочешь получить на выходе? закодированные в 8-битный `alaw` или собстванно 13(16)-битный уровень семпла? для первого понадобится полноценный транскодер, как в примере `transcode_acc`, только вместо acc на выходе нужен alaw... сырой поток, пожатый pcma будет в `AVPacket::buf`, который выдаёт `avcodec_receive_packet`... а, во-втором случае, можно как в примере с `decode_audio.c` в вопросе получить действительно сырые данные от декодера из `avcodec_receive_frame` через `AVFrame->data`...

Comment: В моем случае, пользователь сам должен будет выбрать, что ему нужно. Чаще всего, это будет `pcm_alaw`, так как этот проект будет использован для извлечения аудио данных из аудио файла и заполнение этими данными полезную нагрузку `RTP` пакета. Но возможен и тот случай, когда нужны будут сырые данные (13 bits) для отображения звуковой волны при помощи `SVG`.

Comment: 1. возможно было бы лучше залить запускаемый проект на гитхаб, потому что читать куски кода в таком лонгриде тяжеловато. 2. resampling - это процесс изменения частоты дискретизации, то есть когда уже аудио декодировано и нужно изменить частоту - это resampling. IIRC в ffmpeg есть libresample и она делает именно это. Бегло пробежавшись по тексту (т.е. могу ошибаться) мне показалось что под термином понимается что-то другое. 3. Непонятна причина почему нет конкретной задачи какие данные надо получить. Универсальным форматом декодированных данных является PCМ.

Comment: @RomanR., возможно, вы правы в том, что было бы неплохо загрузить проект на `Github`. А что касается `resampling-а`, то под данным термином, я подразумеваю и изменения частоты дискретизации, и изменения выходного количества каналов, как и изменение формата аудиоданных. Вы правы, что `resampling` используется только после декодирования данных. Но в моем случае, после декодирования данных и применения `resampling-a`, я должен перекодировать полученные данные. Например, при получение `PCM_ALAW`, после декодирования и применения `resampling-a`, на выходе я должен получить PCM_MULAW.